# GORM column names for simple one to many mapping

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have this setup

```
class User {
  Date lastLogin

  // logins is a history of logins
  static hasMany = [logins : Date]

  def setLastLogin(Date date) {
    if (date) {
      lastLogin = date
      addToLogins(date) 
    }
  }
}
```

GORM is generating a table MEMBER_LOGINS which currently looks like this:

```
USER_ID, LOGINS
```

Instead I would like

```
USER_ID, DATE
```

I tried adding a mapping in User

```
static mapping = {
  logins column: 'date';
}
```

But that just changed the foreign key so i now have

```
DATE, LOGINS
```

How can I change the LOGINS column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use hibernate hbm files to map your columns

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html

Or you can do it

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [logins: Date]
    def setLastLogin ...
    static mapping = { 
        hasMany joinTable: 
            [name: 'logins', 
                key: 'person_id', 
                column: 'dates', 
                type: "date"] 
    } 
}
```